# Change the content(icon) of a div when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a list with divs inside and the one div contains a home icon using font awesome. I want the font icon to change to a picture icon when clicked and change back to the home icon when clicked again. Do I need Javascript for this?

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0;
}
li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}
li{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#homecover{
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  left: 47.5%;
  position: absolute;
}

#home{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #F73933;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #F73933 ;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0.1px #9D9494, 0px 0px 0px 1px white inset;
}
#home a{
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <div id="homecover">
    <li id="home">
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></a>
    <li>
   </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: "Clicks" require javascript

Comment: Go with @Jacob-Jan Mosselman answer, you just need to change `fa-picture-o` in place of `fa-anchor`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/otqehbc2/1/

Comment: @KirankumarDafda I went with Jacobs's one, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript, jQuery is recommended:

```
$('#home a').on('click', function(e){
    $('#home span').toggleClass('fa-home fa-anchor');
};
```

I guess you know how to include jQuery, if not just paste this into your head section:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if that works or not!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add jQuery for that:

```js
$("#home a").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
})
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0;
}
li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}
li{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#homecover{
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  left: 47.5%;
  position: absolute;
}

#home{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #F73933;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #F73933 ;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0.1px #9D9494, 0px 0px 0px 1px white inset;
}
#home a{
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
}
#home.active .fa-home:before{
  content: "\f1b9";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <div id="homecover">
    <li id="home">
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></a>
    <li>
   </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Javascript to bind the `click` event, after you should toggle `CSS` class.

Try this solution without `jQuery`

```js
let home = document.querySelector('#home');
    
home.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let icon = document.querySelector('.fa');
  icon.classList.toggle('fa-home');
  icon.classList.toggle('fa-heart');
})
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0;
}
li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}
li{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#homecover{
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  left: 47.5%;
  position: absolute;
}

#home{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #F73933;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #F73933 ;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0.1px #9D9494, 0px 0px 0px 1px white inset;
}
#home a{
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <div id="homecover">
    <li id="home">
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></a>
    <li>
   </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

When user driven events are involved, you'll have to use javascript. One way to do it is, you have two classes and you toggle them to show different icons.

```js
var link = document.querySelector('#home a');
link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  //Prevent default action of a link, which navigates to href prop
  e.preventDefault();
  var icon = this.querySelector('span');
  icon.classList.toggle('fa-home');
  icon.classList.toggle('fa-image');
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0;
}
li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}
li{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#homecover{
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  left: 47.5%;
  position: absolute;
}

#home{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #F73933;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #F73933 ;

  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0.1px #9D9494, 0px 0px 0px 1px white inset;
}
#home a{
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <div id="homecover">
    <li id="home">
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></a>
    <li>
   </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a non js solution

```css
    input + span:before {
      height:45px;
      content:"\f015"
    }
    input:checked + span:before {
      content:"\f03e"
    }
    input{
      display:none;
    }
    span.icon{
      display: block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align:center;
      line-height: 45px;
    }
    ul{
      list-style-type: none;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    li a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    li{
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #homecover{
      cursor:pointer;
      width: 55px;
      height: 55px;
      margin-top: 150px;
      left: 47.5%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    #home{
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      background-color: #F73933;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 2px solid #F73933 ;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0.1px #9D9494, 0px 0px 0px 1px white inset;
    }
    #home a{
      padding-left: 0.5em;
      position: absolute;
      padding-top: 0.3em;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <ul>
      <label class="switch">
      <div id="homecover">
        <li id="home">
          <input type="checkbox" ><span class="icon fa fa-lg"></span>
        <li>
       </div>
      </label>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$("span.fa").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("class") === "fa fa-home"){
          $(this).attr("class", "fa-fa-{any-pic}");
    } else {
          $(this).attr("class", "fa fa-home");
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.